# How do you identify the value of a resistor?

Tags: resistors

What am I overlooking? My Viz-WD0747 multitester measures a four band resistor--Violet, Brown, Orange, Orange (the 4th band does not look gold at all)--as 330 Ohms. My other meter reads it as 523 Ohms. An online calculator give me yet a very different value.

If I read the colors from the other end, the color code indicates the resistance is 71kOhms that is unlikely, given the reading of the meters. So I have two question:

1. Is there a way to determine which end is to be read firstly when the color bands are evenly spaced (not grouped at one end) and without gold or silver to show that the colors must be read from the opposite end?
2. If more than one ohm meter is used to measure the resistance, and each give a very different reading, do you go with the lowest?

---

[image: photo of resistor]

Comment: Show us a photo. Are you measuring this in-circuit or have you removed the resistor from any circuit it may be connected to?

Comment: Is one of the multimeters low on batteries and does it meaaure other resistors wrong as well?

Comment: I added the photo to my OP. So orange must be the color of the first and second band, brown the third and red the multiplier. I thought the third was always the multiplier. No? Reading orange as the first band, another online calculator states the resistor is 33.1kOhms, which is incorrect. It must be 331 Ohms (ignoring the last color, which appears red in the photo but close to violet under good lighting). The resistor was made in the US, so I figure the manufacturer adheres to some kind of standard. I am a novice and trying to learn, so bear with me.

Comment: @Gerard Please don't use the answer system for commenting. I looked for a picture and I couldn't find any edit history.

Comment: (Update: I have copied the OP's photo of the resistor into the question, where they had apparently tried to put it, although we couldn't find any trace of it there from that earlier attempt.)

Comment: The band looks more like red than violet to me. 2% would also make far more sense than 0.1% for a resistor with only 4 bands total.

Comment: To add to Peter Green's comment, the band that looks to me to be red, does not look even remotely violet to me. Perhaps my color vision is changing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing says that the final band must be gold or silver. Gold just means 5% tolerance.

So orange-orange-brown-violet is a perfectly valid code for a 330 ohm 0.1% tolerance resistor.

The other way does not result into a valid code, because orange is not a tolerance code.

One of your multimeters that resulted in 330 ohms proves it.

The other multimeter measures wrong result for some reason, like low battery. You can double-check by measuring a known resistance with both meters.

Comment: 'proves'? Let's just say 'is consistent with'.

Comment: @Neil_UK Proves in the "proving ground" sense.